# How to create random numbers from 4 to 10

Tags: objective-c, random

How can I create a random number within a range? I tried following code but it didn't accomplish my task.

```
int fromNumber = 10;
int toNumber = 30;
int randomNumber = (arc4random()%(toNumber-fromNumber))+fromNumber;
```

Comment: What did it do?  What did you not like about the result?

Comment: What made you use 10 and 30 when you wanted a number between 4 and 10?

Comment: SORRY i just made some mistake while posting but in program it is 4 and 10...

Answer (score 4):

There are seven numbers between 4 and 10 inclusive. [arc4random_uniform()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html) is recommended over arc4random() for this purpose.

```
int randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(7) + 4
```

---

The more general case is `arc4random_uniform(upper_bound - lower_bound + 1) + lower_bound`.

Comment: you beat me by *seconds* =p

Comment: can any body provide me some useful tutorial to lean arc4random and arc4random_uniform

Comment: @user1275440 you should search the web yourself, it is just a function!

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
I was unaware of arc4random_uniform() before so i recommend https://stackoverflow.com/a/18262992/2611613 as the answer. The answer i linked below still has a good explanation of a general approach to this problem without worrying about languages.

---

Your answer should work. Without knowing what is wrong with what you have i can only guess at the problem.

Currently you have

```
int randomNumber = ( arc4random() % ( toNumber - fromNumber ) ) + fromNumber;
```

This produces a range [from-to) exclusive where you will never get the value toNumber. If you want your random number be able to get include toNumber

```
int randomNumber = ( arc4random() % ( toNumber - fromNumber + 1 ) ) + fromNumber;
```

With this you would get a range [from-to] inclusive.

You might look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/363732/2611613 for a really good explanation of how this works.